# SQL Join for retrieving record for a single user

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have user related info split into multiple tables . I am trying to write a join to retrieve data for a single user , a lot of the info is optional , so the entry for many columns may  be null , which is okay . I have written the following query , it is working except that it returns all users when I want the user with id '69'

```
SELECT cur_doctor_names.First_Name, cur_doctor_Names.Last_Name, w.Website
FROM cur_doctor_names
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT *
FROM cur_website
WHERE Userid =69
) AS w ON cur_doctor_names.UserId = w.Userid
```

I want the following result :

```
First_Name | Last Name | Website 
ABC          XYZ         Null
```

where ABC is the name for user with id 69 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only filtering the websites because you are using a left join. You should apply your filter to the doctors table

```
SELECT 
    cur_doctor_names.First_Name, 
    cur_doctor_Names.Last_Name, 
    w.Website 
FROM 
    cur_doctor_names 
        LEFT JOIN cur_website AS w 
        ON cur_doctor_names.UserId = w.Userid 
WHERE     
    cur_doctor_names.UserId = 69
```

Answer (score 2):

Try writing it like this - your where clause was in the wrong place (also your left join does not need to be written like that):

```
SELECT cur_doctor_names.First_Name, cur_doctor_Names.Last_Name, w.Website
FROM cur_doctor_names
  LEFT JOIN cur_website as w
  ON cur_doctor_names.UserId = w.Userid
WHERE cur_doctor_names.userId = 69
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just write

```
SELECT cur_doctor_names.First_Name, cur_doctor_Names.Last_Name, w.Website
FROM cur_doctor_names
LEFT JOIN cur_website w ON cur_doctor_names.UserId = w.Userid
WHERE Userid =69
```